# Differential equations of third order.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm asked to solve this equation $y''-xy'''+(y''')^3=0$ by the reduction of order method. I tried by the change of varaible $p=y''$ and get $p=xp'- (p')^3$, then if I differentiate $p'=p'+xp''-3(p')^2p' \iff xp''+3(p')^2p'=0$, but then I have no idea of how to solve.

Please help me, I think what I've done is incorrect.

Comment: There's a mistake in your calculation: from $p=xp'- (p')^3$, you get $p'=p'+xp''-3(p')^2p''$, i.e. $p''(x-3(p')^2)=0$.

Comment: From $p = xp'-(p')^3$,  you can try solutions $p = a x - b^3$ to get $b = a$. Integrate twice and you are done.

Answer (score 1):

As was already mentioned, you missed noting one derivation. However, just before that you already found the form
$$
p=p'x-(p')^3
$$
which is a Clairaut differential equation with a linear solution family
$$
y''=p=Cx-C^3\implies y=A+Bx+\frac{C}6x^3-\frac{C^3}{2}x^2
$$
and a singular solution
$$
x=3p'^2\implies y''=p=\frac23p'x=\pm\frac2{3^{3/2}}x^{3/2}
$$
which also can be now easily further integrated.